# fmod or not fmod?

Tags: c++, c, math

I dug into old code, and saw a function like this:

```
inline double mod(double x, double y)
{
    return x-y*floor(x/y);
}
```

is `fmod` its full equivalent, or have I missed something?

Comment: You should read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the above routine it is not the same as `fmod()`. Specifically it is different for situations where one argument is negative.

Your routine does a `floor()`, which rounds down to the next integer. With `fmod()` the rounding is like `trunc()`, i.e. towards zero.

Here's an extract from the Open Group standard ([here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fmod.html)):

> These functions shall return the value `x- i* y`, for some integer `i` such that, if `y` is non-zero, the result has the same sign as `x` and magnitude less than the magnitude of `y`.
>
> If the correct value would cause underflow, and is not representable, a range error may occur, and either 0.0 (if supported), or an implementation-defined value shall be returned.
>
> If `x` or `y` is `NaN`, a `NaN` shall be returned
>
> If `y` is zero, a domain error shall occur, and either a `NaN` (if supported), or an implementation-defined value shall be returned.
>
> If `x` is infinite, a domain error shall occur, and either a `NaN` (if supported), or an implementation-defined value shall be returned.
>
> If `x` is `±0` and `y` is not zero, `±0` shall be returned.
>
> If `x` is not infinite and y is`±Inf`, `x` shall be returned.
>
> If the correct value would cause underflow, and is representable, a range error may occur and the correct value shall be returned.

That's difficult to understand, but the word '*magnitude*' in the first paragraph illustrates the rounding is towards zero.

Here's an extract from the much more helpful documentation for the GCC library:

> These functions compute the remainder from the division of numerator by denominator. Specifically, the return value is `numerator` - `n` * `denominator`, where `n` is the quotient of `numerator` divided by `denominator`, rounded towards zero to an integer. Thus, `fmod` (6.5, 2.3) returns 1.9, which is 6.5 minus 4.6.

Comment: It was probably intended to behave exactly the same as `fmod`, but fell prey to one of the most common pitfalls in rounding.

Comment: @jaggedSpire - oops. Yes, quite right. Like `trunc()` - fixed.

Comment: @GuyGreer Why do you say that? Lots of languages/libraries explicitly implement their modulus operator as behaving differently than c's `fmod` (and following the convention's of OP's function instead). This is true of e.g. Python. This convention also makes testing for congruency (test if there is some integer `k` such that `a == b + k*y`) *much* easier, so I imagine it's the typical implementation in cryptography applications too.